# super() built-in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, class, super

I wrote the following code in python (to practice), but I can not figure out where the error is:

```
class BClass:
    def __init__ (self, message):
        self.message=message
    def printMessage(self):
        print(self.message)

class AClass(BClass):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(). __init__(message)

m1=AClass("ciao")
m1.printMessage()
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You have a syntactically erroneous space after the `.` in `super(). __init__(message)`.

Comment: @Synook When I run with python3 I get no error. When I run with python 2.7 I get *TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)* - even after removing the space.

Comment: @Synook
I fixed the code but it returns this error:
`code` m1=AClass("ciao")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
`code`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments this topic has been discussed before. I found this link cuts to the chase of your problem [super in python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072278/super-in-python-2-7) However, here is a solution for your particular case that works for python2.7:

```
class BClass(object):
    message = ''
    def __init__ (self, message):
        self.message=message
    def printMessage(self):
        print(self.message)

class AClass(BClass):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(AClass, self).__init__(message)

m1=AClass("ciao")
m1.printMessage()
```