# How to use super() to call base class function in python 2.7.13?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have a multilevel inheritance (A->B->C). In base class i have a dictionary variable called "my_dict". From derived class, I am calling base class function by super().add_to_dict() to add some values.

Below code works as expected in python 3.7. But in Python 2.7.13 it throws error. can some one help me to fix it for 2.7.13?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_dict = OrderedDict()
    def add_to_dict(self):
        self.my_dict["zero"]=0
        self.my_dict["one"]=1 


class B(A):
    def add_to_dict(self):
        super().add_to_dict()
        self.my_dict["two"]=2
    def print_dict(self):
        print("class B {}".format(my_dict))


class C(B):
    def add_to_dict(self):
        super().add_to_dict()
        self.my_dict["three"]=3
    def print_dict(self):
        print("class C {}".format(self.my_dict))
obj = C()
obj.add_to_dict()
obj.print_dict()
```

> **Output ( 2.7.13):**
>
> File "test.py", line 15, in add_to_dict
>       super().add_to_dict()
>
> **TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)**

**Output (python 3.7)**

class C OrderedDict([('zero', 0), ('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [super in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072278/super-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In py2 you can use `super(<Class>, <instance>).<function>()`. Those are also have to be "new style" classes. Those are defined by inheriting from `object`.

So in your case proper code should be:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_dict = OrderedDict()
    def add_to_dict(self):
        self.my_dict["zero"]=0
        self.my_dict["one"]=1


class B(A):
    def add_to_dict(self):
        super(B, self).add_to_dict()
        self.my_dict["two"]=2
    def print_dict(self):
        print("class B {}".format(my_dict))


class C(B):
    def add_to_dict(self):
        super(C, self).add_to_dict()
        self.my_dict["three"]=3
    def print_dict(self):
        print("class C {}".format(self.my_dict))
```

Comment: I tried it, but got this error :"TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj"

Comment: @utek . Thanks i was missing the new type object. class A(object):  :)